# Swift, NSJSONSerialization and NSError

Tags: swift, nsjsonserialization, nserror

The problem is when there is incomplete data `NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData` is crashing  the application giving `unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value` error instead of informing us using NSError variable. So we are unable to prevent crash.

You can find code we are using below

```
      var error:NSError? = nil

      let dataToUse = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(receivedData, options:   NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments, error:&error) as NSDictionary

    if error != nil { println( "There was an error in NSJSONSerialization") }
```

Till now we are unable to find a work around.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The problem is that you cast the result of the JSON deserialization *before*
checking for an error. If the JSON data is invalid (e.g. incomplete) then

```
NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(...)
```

returns `nil` and

```
NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(...) as NSDictionary
```

will crash.

Here is a version that checks for the error conditions correctly:

```
var error:NSError? = nil
if let jsonObject: AnyObject = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(receivedData, options: nil, error:&error) {
    if let dict = jsonObject as? NSDictionary {
        println(dict)
    } else {
        println("not a dictionary")
    }
} else {
    println("Could not parse JSON: \(error!)")
}
```

Remarks:

- The correct way to check for an error is to test the *return value*, not the
  error variable.
- The JSON reading option `.AllowFragments` does not help here. Setting this option
  only allows that top-level objects that are not an instance of `NSArray` or `NSDictionary`, for example

  ```
  { "someString" }
  ```

You can also do it in one line, with an *optional cast* `as?`:

```
if let dict = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(receivedData, options: nil, error:nil) as? NSDictionary {
    println(dict)
} else {
    println("Could not read JSON dictionary")
}
```

The disadvantage is that in the `else` case you cannot distinguish whether reading
the JSON data failed or if the JSON did not represent a dictionary.

For an update to Swift 3, see [LightningStryk's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31926399/1187415).

Comment: The part you explained as "Here is a version that checks for the error conditions correctly"  is not catching the error either. It is crushed at the line unfortunately                 let dataToUse: AnyObject = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(receivedData, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments, error:&error)!   I'd like the say that this and previous codes I submitted works just fine in case of there is no problem with the received data.

Comment: @Hope: That is not exactly what I suggested. If you forcefully unwrap the result with `!` then you have the same problem as with the forced cast `as NSDictionary`:  It will crash if the result is nil.

Comment: let dataToUse: AnyObject? = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(receivedData, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments, error:&error)  Seems to be OK. So I am checking question as answered by you. At least your grasp about the subject is better.

Answer (score 49):

Updated for Swift 3

```
let jsonData = Data()
do {
    let jsonObject = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData, options:JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions(rawValue: 0))
    guard let dictionary = jsonObject as? Dictionary<String, Any> else {
        print("Not a Dictionary")
        // put in function
        return
    }
    print("JSON Dictionary! \(dictionary)")
}
catch let error as NSError {
    print("Found an error - \(error)")
}
```

Swift 2

```
let JSONData = NSData()
do {
    let JSON = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(JSONData, options:NSJSONReadingOptions(rawValue: 0))
    guard let JSONDictionary: NSDictionary = JSON as? NSDictionary else {
        print("Not a Dictionary")
        // put in function
        return
    }
    print("JSONDictionary! \(JSONDictionary)")
}
catch let JSONError as NSError {
    print("\(JSONError)")
}
```

Comment: ouch swift really has an awful syntax compared to objc. "let", "do", "try", "guard", "as?", "catch"...so much jargon.

Comment: It would be way better if you could just catch the runtime exception of it failing to cast to the NSDictionary, can't believe they had to add a whole new keyword guard just to make this possible.

Comment: Using capital first letters for variable names is a bad idea, you are confusing people. But at the same time, thanks for this answer.

Comment: If the variable is an acronym (e.g. JSON, URL, etc.) I prefer to capitalize the whole word, otherwise it looks odd (jSON, uRL)

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 3:**

```
let jsonData = Data()
do {
    guard let parsedResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData, options: .allowFragments) as? NSDictionary else {
        return
    }
    print("Parsed Result: \(parsedResult)")
} catch {
    print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Swift 2 extension you can use to deserialise only an NSDictionary:

```
extension NSJSONSerialization{
    public class func dictionaryWithData(data: NSData, options opt: NSJSONReadingOptions) throws -> NSDictionary{
        guard let d: NSDictionary = try self.JSONObjectWithData(data, options:opt) as? NSDictionary else{
            throw NSError(domain: NSURLErrorDomain, code: NSURLErrorCannotParseResponse, userInfo: [NSLocalizedDescriptionKey : "not a dictionary"])
        }
        return d;
    }
}
```

Sorry I wasn't sure how to do a guard return to avoid creating the temporary 'd'.

Answer (score 0):

Swift 3 NSJSONSerialization sample (read json from file):

> file data.json (example from here: http://json.org/example.html)

```
{
"glossary":{
"title":"example glossary",
"GlossDiv":{
    "title":"S",
    "GlossList":{
        "GlossEntry":{
            "ID":"SGML",
            "SortAs":"SGML",
            "GlossTerm":"Standard Generalized Markup Language",
            "Acronym":"SGML",
            "Abbrev":"ISO 8879:1986",
            "GlossDef":{
                "para":"A meta-markup language, used to create markup languages such as DocBook.",
                "GlossSeeAlso":[
                                "GML",
                                "XML"
                                ]
            },
            "GlossSee":"markup"
        }
    }
}
}
}
```

> file JSONSerialization.swift

```
extension JSONSerialization {

enum Errors: Error {
    case NotDictionary
    case NotJSONFormat
}

public class func dictionary(data: Data, options opt: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions) throws -> NSDictionary {
    do {
        let JSON = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data , options:opt)
        if let JSONDictionary = JSON as? NSDictionary {
            return JSONDictionary
        }
        throw Errors.NotDictionary
    }
    catch {
        throw Errors.NotJSONFormat
    }
}
}
```

### Usage

```
 func readJsonFromFile() {
    if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "data", ofType: "json") {
        if let data = NSData(contentsOfFile: path) as? Data {

            do {
                let dict = try JSONSerialization.dictionary(data: data, options: .allowFragments)
                print(dict)
            } catch let error {
                print("\(error)")
            }

        }
    }
}
```

### Result (log screenshot)

[image]